# Custom Json Converter For Passing DateTimeOffset between Blazor and JS. JS property Input/Output are different types

Tags: c#, json, blazor, system.text.json, blazor-jsinterop

I have a scenario where I have to serialize a `DateTimeOffset` to JSON as a simple string value (e.g. `"2021-04-07T18:18:00.000Z"`, but deserialize it as a value embedded in an object (e.g. `{"_date":"2021-04-07T18:18:00.000Z"}`).  How can I do that with `System.Text.Json`?

The details are as follows.  I am wrapping a [calendar UI lib](https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/Schedule) for blazor. I have wrapped the JS classes with C# classes. When sending a calendar "schedule" (event) from Blazor to JS, the DateTimes are just passed as serialized strings. This works.

When sending a "schedule" from JS to Blazor, it comes back as an object(TZdate) and inside is a "_date" property.

The json object that comes back looks like this:

```
{
"end":{
      "_date":"2021-04-07T18:18:00.000Z"
       }
}
```

I've tried writing a custom converter for DateTimeOffset. Here is the read method:

```cs
        public override DateTimeOffset Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(JsonDocument.Parse(reader.GetString()).RootElement.EnumerateObject().First().Value.EnumerateObject().First().Value.GetString(),
             TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The above doesn't work. I don't believe I'm using the `reader` class correctly or how to extract the "_date" from the json here.

Alternatively, I tried wrapping my DateTimeOffset Property with a new "TZDate" class and a property "_date", but this breaks on the JS side as the library is expecting a simple datetime string from C#, not an object.

Changing the JS library is probably not option.

What are my options or how do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DateTimeOffset` value is embedded inside an object like so:

```json
{"_date":"2021-04-07T18:18:00.000Z"}
```

And you would like to extract the value of the inner `_date` property to return.  You can do that using the following `JsonConverter<DateTime>.Read()` method:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    const string TZDateFormat = "O"; // Your custom format (not shown in your question).

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        // Write as a simple string.
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    
    const string _date = "_date";

    public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonTokenType.String:
                // A simple DateTimeOffset string "value"
                return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
            {
                // A DateTimeOffset string embedded in an object { "_date" : "value" }
                using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
                if (doc.RootElement.TryGetProperty(_date, out var value))
                    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value.GetString(), TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return default(DateTimeOffset); // Or throw an exception?
            }
            default:
                throw new JsonException(); // Unknown token type
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Read()` method you attempt to load the value returned by `reader.GetString()` into a `JsonDocument`, but at the beginning of the method the reader is positioned on the `StartObject` token not a value string, and [`reader.GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.getstring?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_GetString) only returns the string value of the *current token*, not the current token *and its children* as you would seem to want.  To load the current token and its children into a `JsonDocument`, use [`JsonDocument.ParseValue(Utf8JsonReader)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parsevalue?view=net-5.0).

(As an aside, [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument) is disposable, and in fact must be disposed to return pooled memory back to the memory pool.)

If you would like to avoid constructing a `JsonDocument` you can stream through the JSON directly using just the `Utf8JsonReader` as follows:

```
static byte [] _date = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("_date");

public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    switch (reader.TokenType)
    {
        case JsonTokenType.String:
            // A simple DateTimeOffset string "value"
            return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
        {
            // A DateTimeOffset string embedded in an object { "_date" : "value" }
            DateTimeOffset? value = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonTokenType.EndObject:
                        return value.GetValueOrDefault();
                    case JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
                        var match = reader.ValueTextEquals(_date);
                        reader.Read();
                        if (match)
                            value = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), TZDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        else
                            reader.Skip();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new JsonException();
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    throw new JsonException();
}
```

This is a bit more complex but should also be more performant.

In both cases I check to see whether the incoming value is an object or a simple string.  If a simple string, I go ahead and parse it as a `DateTimeOffset`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CHhDEV).

Comment: Fantastic answer and detail. Thank you. This is what I was looking to do. My work-around last night around was to make two converters. One for DateTimeOffset and another for the TzDate class/object. The TzDate object Write Method simply outputs the _date Property as a string and reading returns the object with the _date property. Extra layers and clunky-ness. I will implement what you have detailed here.